# Ruby on Rails 4 - Rspec: count should have been changed by 1, but was changed by 0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4, factory-bot

I'm currently working on a Ruby on Rails Application and I'm new to testing. A few day ago I started to write tests using the gems `rspec-rails`, `factory_girl_rails` and `faker`.

Writing tests for model validations was quite easy, but now I'm stuck at writing controller tests.
I have a simple class "Message", which I created by using the scaffold command.

SCHEMA:

```
create_table "messages", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.string   "email"
  t.string   "text"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"   end
```

When I try to run the following test..

spec/controllers/messages_controller_spec.rb:

```
  describe "POST create" do
    describe "with valid params" do
      it "creates a new Message" do
        expect {
          post :create, FactoryGirl.create(:message)
        }.to change(Message, :count).by(1)
      end
    end
  end
```

..I get this error message..

> MessagesController   POST create
>       with valid params
>         creates a new Message (FAILED - 1)
>
> Failures:
>
> 1) MessagesController POST create with valid params creates a new
>   Message
>        Failure/Error: expect {
>          count should have been changed by 1, but was changed by 0

..by using this factories:

spec/factories/message.rb:

```
require "faker"

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :message do |m|
    m.name { Faker::Name.name }
    m.email { Faker::Internet.email }
    m.text { Faker::Lorem.sentences }
  end
end
```

I've been searching HOURS for an answer - but so far I haven't found a solution that works for me. I hope anyone out there can help me!

Thanks!

This is my Model: (But even if I remove all validations I get the same error message)

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, :email, :text,
    presence: { 
      value:  :true,
      message: "ist ein Pflichtfeld"
    }

    validates :name, length: { maximum: 50,
        too_long: "ist zu lang" }

    validates :email, length: { maximum: 50,
        too_long: "ist zu lang" }

    validates :text, length: { maximum: 10000,
        too_long: "ist zu lang" }

end
```

This is my create action:

```
  def create

    @message = Message.new(message_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @message.save
        format.html { redirect_to action: 'new' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @message }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @message.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Function: message_params

```
def message_params
  params.require(:message).permit(:name, :email, :text)
end
```

Comment: can you show the message model?

Comment: Where is the `Message` supposed to be created? In the rspec (calling `FactoryGirl.create(:message)` or in the controller(calling `post :create,...`)?

Comment: This is what my Message Model looks like: class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, :email, :text,
    presence: { 
      value:  :true,
      message: "ist ein Pflichtfeld"
    }
  
 validates :name, length: { maximum: 50,
     too_long: "ist zu lang" }

 validates :email, length: { maximum: 50,
     too_long: "ist zu lang" }

 validates :text, length: { maximum: 10000,
     too_long: "ist zu lang" }

end

Answer (score 2):

Use `attributes_for` method which returns a hash of attributes that can be used to build an instance of Message.

```
 describe "POST create" do
    describe "with valid params" do
      it "creates a new Message" do
        expect {
          post :create, FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:message) ## Use attributes_for
        }.to change(Message, :count).by(1)
      end
    end
  end
```

`FactoryGirl.create(:message)` would actually save a record in the `messages` table.
For controller testing, you just have to pass a hash of attributes and `post :create` would call the `MessagesController#create` action which in turn would save the record in database.

**EDIT**

Replace  `m.text { Faker::Lorem.sentences }` with `m.text { Faker::Lorem.paragraph }`.
As `sentences` returns an Array of Strings whereas field `text` in Model `message` requires a String. This will result in an error and fail to save the record.

```
require "faker"

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :message do |m|
    m.name { Faker::Name.name }
    m.email { Faker::Internet.email }
    m.text { Faker::Lorem.paragraph } ## Use paragraph instead of sentences
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I still get this error: Failure/Error: expect {
       count should have been changed by 1, but was changed by 0

Comment: Please share the `Message` model and `MessagesController#create` action.

Comment: This is my model: class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, :email, :text,
    presence: { 
      value:  :true,
      message: "ist ein Pflichtfeld"
    }
  
 validates :name, length: { maximum: 50,
     too_long: "ist zu lang" }

 validates :email, length: { maximum: 50,
     too_long: "ist zu lang" }

 validates :text, length: { maximum: 10000,
     too_long: "ist zu lang" }

end

Comment: Also share the create_params method. Add it in the question and not in the comment so its more readable .

Comment: Oh sorry - added it to the question... Any idea? :(

Comment: Replace `m.text { Faker::Lorem.sentences }` with `  m.text { Faker::Lorem.paragraph }`. Try and let me know the result.

Comment: See the explanation under the EDIT section in the answer.